# How to read the table name from query by using DataTable in C# winforms

Tags: c#

EX: `DataTable Dt = connectionname.ReadTable("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER");`

Now I want to read the tablename which is "CUSTOMER" in query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataTable.TableName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string nameOfTable = Dt.TableName;
```

But if that property is set depends on the way you fill the `DataTable`.

If you specify the name of the table in `DbDataAdapter.Fill` this property is set:

```
adapter.Fill(dataSet, "CUSTOMER");
```

But you can always set it yourself, for example in `connectionname.ReadTable`.

Apart from that **there is no way** to extract the `TableName` from a sql query.

- if you look at the sql string `CUSTOMER` could also be a view, common-table-expression, named subquery or table-valued-function. Neither a `SqlDataAdapter`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlReader` or `DataSet`/`DataTable` knows the name of the table if it was not set manually.
- Note that a sql query can also select from multiple tables and the result set can also contain multiple result-sets(selected from multiple tables, f.e. `SELECT * FROM Table1; SELECT * FROM Table2;`).

Answer (score 1):

In case the SQL originates from user input, you can parse the table names out of the string, like this:

```
string sql = "your query goes here";
int fromPos = sql.IndexOf("from ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
if (fromPos == -1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No FROM in the SQL, unable to parse tables.");
    return;
}

string fromPart = sql.Substring(fromPos);

Regex tableRegex = new Regex(@"from\s*(\w*)|join\s*(\w*)|,\s*(\w*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

var ms = tableRegex.Matches(fromPart);

List<string> usedTableNames = new List<string>();

foreach (Match m in ms)
{
    string tableName = m.Groups[1].Value;
    if (tableName == "") tableName = m.Groups[2].Value;
    if (tableName == "") tableName = m.Groups[3].Value;
    usedTableNames.Add(tableName.ToUpperInvariant());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DataTable Dt = connectionname.ReadTable("SELECT 'CUSTOMER' as TableName,* FROM CUSTOMER");
```

Comment: Even if its an answer it is a good practice to add some text commenting how it works.